# Docker registry on Artifactory - login failed

Tags: docker, nginx, artifactory

I am trying to set up docker registry on artifactory (Version 5.4.6). I have the service working behind NGINX as described in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry.

I configured a docker registry with a number of repositories. All repositories use API Version: V2.

I followed the subdomain approach: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-TheSubdomainMethod .

I can not log in:

```
$ docker -D login docker-local.artifactory.example.com
Username: admin
Password:
Error response from daemon: Login: {
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 404,
"message" : "Not Found"
} ] } (Code: 404; Headers: map[Date:[Tue, 19 Sep 2017 16:56:56 GMT] Content-Type:[application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1] Content-Length:[74] Server:[Artifactory/5.4.6] X-Artifactory-Id:[f7687bf2b01c0581:a28d522:15e9afc2ee7:-8000]])
```

$ tail -f /opt/artifactory/logs/artifactory.log

```
2017-09-19 13:15:46,526 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RequestUtils:155) - Request /v2/ should be a repo request and does not match any repo key
2017-09-19 13:15:47,204 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RequestUtils:155) - Request /v2/ should be a repo request and does not match any repo key
2017-09-19 13:15:47,873 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RequestUtils:155) - Request /v1/users/ should be a repo request and does not match any repo key
```

Initially tested with:

```
$ curl -I -k -v https://docker-local.artifactory.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://docker-local.artifactory.example.com/
*   Trying 10.145.77.66...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to docker-local.artifactory.example.com (10.145.77.66) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=PL; ST=Poland; L=Warsaw; O=Project YELLOW; OU=Test; CN=*.artifactory.example.com; emailAddress=k.marek@example.com
*  start date: Sep 19 11:37:53 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 19 11:37:53 2018 GMT
*  issuer: C=PL; ST=Poland; L=Warsaw; O=Project YELLOW; OU=Test; CN=*.artifactory.example.com; emailAddress=k.marek@example.com
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: docker-local.artifactory.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 17:20:31 GMT
Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 17:20:31 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 170
Content-Length: 170
< Location: https://docker-local.artifactory.example.com/webapp/
Location: https://docker-local.artifactory.example.com/webapp/
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host docker-local.artifactory.example.com left intact
```

My docker:

```
$ docker version
Client:
Version:      1.12.6
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.7.4
Git commit:   78d1802
Built:        Tue Mar 14 09:47:15 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.12.6
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.7.4
Git commit:   78d1802
Built:        Tue Mar 14 09:47:15 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

NGINX:

```
###########################################################
## this configuration was generated by JFrog Artifactory ##
###########################################################

## add ssl entries when https has been set in config
ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
## server configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80 ;
    server_name ~(?<repo>.+)\.artifactory.example.com artifactory.example.com;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory.example.com-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory.example.com-error.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^//?(/webapp)?$ /webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/$repo/$1/$2;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    location / {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)$ ) {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/artifactory/$1;
    }
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header    X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

What am I missing ?
Please help

Comment: have you done this: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry

Comment: Yes I did, as well as https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-GettingStartedwithArtifactoryProOn-Prem

Comment: They are mentioning in that post port 5001 have you tried docker login docker-local.artifactory.example.com:5001?

Comment: From what I understand there are 2 way to set this up. Subdomain method, which I chose - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-TheSubdomainMethod and the PortMethod, which you are referring to. No I did not tried it.

Comment: What repository key have you specified when you've created a new local repository?

Comment: I have several repositories, 'docker-local' is one of them. For local repository 'docker-local' Repository key is set to 'docker-local'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue ([RTFACT-13862](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-13862)) with the subdomain method due to the mechanic that is being used to assure that NGINX does not decode certain characters. This mechanism is preventing the Docker calls from being made properly to the upstream. You can easily fix this by removing these three lines:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)$ ) {
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/artifactory/$1;
}
```

The main reason for that snippet was for NPM packages that used the encoded forward slash (%2f) which NGINX would decode to the simple forward slash (thus resulting in a different request) but you are using a version of Artifatory that knows contextually when it should treat a decoded slash as an encoded one so you are not likely to need it.

Comment: It works, Thank You!

$ docker -D login docker-local.artifactory.example.com
Username: admin
Password:
Login Succeeded